# Как работают interface в Java

Tags: java, android, интерфейс

Осваивая программирование с Java под Android,  столкнулся с такой проблемой: не могу прочитать/понять пример из книги. Есть два класса (наследники AppCompatActivity и ListFragment). Я не могу въехать как они взаимодействуют. Вот сам код.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WorkoutListFragment.WorkoutListListener{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //WorkoutDetailFragment fragment = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
    //fragment.setWorkoutId(1);
  }

  @Override
  public void itemClicked(long id) {
    WorkoutDetailFragment details = new WorkoutDetailFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    details.setWorkoutId(id);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, details);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
  }
}
```

и второй

```
public class WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment {

  public WorkoutListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  static interface WorkoutListListener{
    void itemClicked(long id);
  }

  private WorkoutListListener mListener;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] names = new String[Workout.workouts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        names[i] = Workout.workouts[i].getName();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),
                                                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                            names);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_list, container, false);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mListener = (WorkoutListListener) context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if (mListener != null){
        mListener.itemClicked(id);
    }
  }
}
```

Почему при клики по item в ListFragment должен вызываться код из активности?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В методе `onAttach` передается `Context` - это та самая `Activity`, она приводится к `WorkoutListListener` (им и является, раз реализует этот интерфейс) и сохраняется в поле `mListener`. При нажатии пункта списка, грубо говоря, вызывается метод активити.

Можно было бы сделать так:

```
@Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ((WorkoutListListener)getActivity()).itemClicked(id);
  }
```

Comment: Да. Теперь понял. Спасибо большое!